# Handling malformed Querystring in `Page_Load`

Tags: jquery, asp.net, query-string

I'd like to open up a modal error box with a message and a button redirecting the user from `Page_Load` event when the incoming `Querystring` does not contain a required attribute, or if it's malformed.

I've defined a `jQuery` function for opening the dialog, but when I try to register it through `RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, it does not show up.

```cs
function showErrorPopup() {
    $('#errorDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 120,
        width: 500,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Error!",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        },
        close: function (type, data) {
            $('#addNoteButton').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#errorDialog').dialog("open");
    $('#addNoteButton').hide();
}
```

And on `Page_Load`:

```cs
string cID = Page.Request["c"];
int contractID = 0;
if (cID != null)
{
    try
    {
        contractID = Convert.ToInt32(cID);
        Contract contract = FacadeFactory.ProjectsFacade.GetContract(contractID);
        TFSContract source = TFS.GetTFSContract(contract);
        Contract = source;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        errMessage.Text = "Zakázka s tímto číslem neexistuje!";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, script, true);
        return;
    }

}
else
{
    errMessage.Text = "Zakázka s tímto číslem neexistuje!";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), this.UniqueID, script, true);
    return;
}
```

Can somebody please tell me how this can be achieved?

Comment: The way you do it - but what you error you get ? what is your code ?

Comment: I don't get an error, the dialog just doesn't show up.